# Automatically move menu to use space efficiently?

Tags: html, css, mobile, menu, position

I am trying to make a device friendly version of a website but I am having some issues with the menu. I will struggle to fit it all on an ipad screen without scrolling but it would help if the menus automatically shifted up to fill in the blank space.

The blue areas are menus and black areas are wasted space. Is there any way to get my menu to shift up to the bottom of the above menu?

HTML

```
<ul><t2>Home</t2>

        </ul>



        <ul><t2>Academic Life</t2>
            <li>Test 1</li>
            <li>Test 2</li>
            <li>Test 3</li>
            <li>Test 4</li>
        </ul>



        <ul><t2>A Catholic Education</t2>
            <li>Test 1</li>
            <li>Test 2</li>
            <li>Test 3</li>
            <li>Test 4</li>
        </ul>



        <ul><t2>Sporting & Co-Curricular</t2>
            <li>Test 1</li>
            <li>Test 2</li>
            <li>Test 3</li>
            <li>Test 4</li>
        </ul>



        <ul><t2>Music & The Arts</t2>
            <li>Test 1</li>
            <li>Test 2</li>
            <li>Test 3</li>
            <li>Test 4</li>
        </ul>



        <ul><t2>Sixth Form</t2>
            <li>Test 1</li>
            <li>Test 2</li>
            <li>Test 3</li>
            <li>Test 4</li>
        </ul>



        <ul><t2>Information</t2>
            <li>Test 1</li>
            <li>Test 2</li>
            <li>Test 3</li>
            <li>Test 4</li>
        </ul>



        <ul><t2>News</t2>

        </ul>



        <ul><t2>Events</t2>

        </ul>
```

CSS -

```
body {
    background-color: #000;
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    width: 48%;
    min-width: 460px;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: blue;
    font-family: Gill Sans MT;
    color: #fff;
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    font-size: 40px;
    position: relative;
}

t2 {
    font-size: 100%;
}

li {
    font-size: 80%;
    padding-left: 3%;
}

@media all and (orientation:landscape) {

    ul {
        width: 32%;
        min-width: 300px;
        font-size: 30px;
    }

    .menuicon {
        width: 100px;
    }

    #menu {
        padding-top: 105px;
    }
}
```

Any help would be hugely appreciated!
Thanks.

Comment: what about using the @media screen size aswell as orientation, have a look [here, css-tricks media queries](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/)

Comment: Hi Billy, thanks for your comment. When the screen size shrinks they stack one on top of the other, but when the page is landscape, it has a menu which is 3 items across. This does not use the space layout very well. here is a JSFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=E3s6hzs8C8

Comment: quick look and your nesting lists incorrectly, ul then ul should be ul li then a ul inside that. Whats a t tag, never came across it before ## EDIT just seen that you are closing the ul's. why don't you nest lists, that will close the space, give me a few mins.

Comment: I think it is cause most of the style was defined in the <ul> so I may have to shuffle some things. I will let you know what the outcome is. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

correctly nested now, the blank spaces were due to them being seperate lists, changed t2 for h2, which is what I presume you meant, I may be wrong on that but I've never heard of a t tag, if i'm wrong, which I remember I was once in 1982 about my then girlfriends cats name, then change the css h2 to t2 and change the html tags back. haven't touched the css apart from that

```css
body {
    background-color: #000;
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    width: 48%;
    min-width: 460px;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: blue;
    font-family: Gill Sans MT;
    color: #fff;
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    font-size: 40px;
    position: relative;
}

h2 {
    font-size: 100%;
}

li {
    font-size: 80%;
    padding-left: 3%;
}

@media all and (orientation:landscape) {

    ul {
        width: 32%;
        min-width: 300px;
        font-size: 30px;
    }

    .
```

```html
<ul>
   <li>
        <h2>
    Home
     </h2>
      </li>
 <li>
  <ul>
   <li>
    <h2>
     Academic Life
    </h2>
   </li>
            <li>Test 1</li>
            <li>Test 2</li>
            <li>Test 3</li>
            <li>Test 4</li>
        </ul>
       </li>
    <li>
   <ul>
    <li>
     <h2>A Catholic Education</h2>
    </li>
    <li>Test 1</li>
    <li>Test 2</li>
    <li>Test 3</li>
    <li>Test 4</li>
   </ul>
        </li>
  <li>
   <ul>
    <li>
     <h2>Sporting & Co-Curricular</h2>
    </li>
    <li>Test 1</li>
    <li>Test 2</li>
    <li>Test 3</li>
    <li>Test 4</li>
   </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
   <ul>
    <li>
     <h2>Music & The Arts</h2>
    </li>
    <li>Test 1</li>
    <li>Test 2</li>
    <li>Test 3</li>
    <li>Test 4</li>
   </ul>



        </li><li><ul><li><h2>Sixth Form</h2></li>
            <li>Test 1</li>
            <li>Test 2</li>
            <li>Test 3</li>
            <li>Test 4</li>
        </ul>



        </li><li><ul><li><h2>Information</h2></li>
            <li>Test 1</li>
            <li>Test 2</li>
            <li>Test 3</li>
            <li>Test 4</li>
        </ul>



        </li>
        <li>
          <ul>
            <li><h2>News</h2></li>

          </ul>



        </li>
  <li><ul><li><h2>Events</h2></li>

        </ul>
    </ul>
```

Comment: Hi Billy, thanks again for your help. This is sort of the outcome I was after but it no longer stacks to the left depending on the page width :( any clues?

Comment: all i changed in the css was t2 to h2 so something else wrong. is that all the css on the page ?  I didn't have time to indent all your code properly so if i was you I would do that and double check that it all opens and closes properly, Quick look and i think i missed a closing li at the bottom. You should indent your code like the start of mine, Makes it 100% easier to debug ##EDIT mine doesn't look too neat on here but it is better on my notepad++